View not displaying text from a list
I have a CalendarView that passes an array of appointments to DayView. The appointments seem to pass fine and I have verified that the view code is running, but nothing is displaying. I tried cleaning the build folder. Any thoughts here?
The code that is not displaying is:
           List {
                ForEach(appointments) { appointment in
                    DayCellView(appointment: appointment)
                }
            }

the entirety of the view is:
import SwiftUI

struct DayView: View {
    var appointments: [Appointment] = []
    
    @State var dates = [
            Date(),
            Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .minute, value: 30, to: Date()),
            Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .hour, value: 60, to: Date()),
            Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .hour, value: 90, to: Date()),
            Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .hour, value: 120, to: Date())
        ]
        .compactMap { $0 }
    
    @State var selectedDate: Date?
    
    @State var currentDate: Date
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            
            List {
                ForEach(appointments) { appointment in
                    DayCellView(appointment: appointment)
                }
            }
            
            VStack {
                Text(currentDate.fullMonthDayYearFormat())
                
                Divider()
                    .padding(.vertical)
                
                Text("Select a Time")
                    .font(.largeTitle)
                    .bold()
                
                Text("Duration: 15 minutes")
                
                ForEach(dates, id: \.self) { date in
                    HStack {
                        Button {
                            withAnimation {
                                selectedDate = date
                            }
                        } label: {
                           
                            Text( (date.timeFromDate()))
                                .bold()
                                .padding()
                                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                                .foregroundColor(selectedDate == date ? .white : .blue)
                                .background(ZStack {
                                    if selectedDate == date {
                                        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10).foregroundColor(.gray)
                                    } else {
                                        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10).stroke()
                                    }
                                }
                                )
                    }
                        if selectedDate == date {
                            NavigationLink {
                                if let resident = NetworkViewModel.resident {
                                    BookingView( appointment: Appointment(residentID: resident.id!, firstName: "", lastName: "", phoneNumber: "", date: selectedDate!, time: selectedDate!.timeFromDate(), description: "", house: "", residentAddress: "", addressOfAppt: "", hasRideScheduled: false))
                                }
                                
                            } label: {
                               Text("Next")
                                    .bold()
                                    .padding()
                                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                                    .background(
                                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
                                        .foregroundColor(.blue)
                                    )
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                .padding(.horizontal)
            }
        }
        .navigationTitle(currentDate.dayOfWeek())
        .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
        .onAppear {
            dates = timesWith30MinuteIncrements(for: currentDate)
        }
    }
    
    func timesWith30MinuteIncrements(for date: Date) -> [Date] {
        let calendar = Calendar.current
        let startDate = calendar.date(bySettingHour: 8, minute: 0, second: 0, of: date)!
        let endDate = calendar.date(bySettingHour: 18, minute: 0, second: 0, of: date)!
        
        var times: [Date] = []
        var currentDate = startDate
        while currentDate <= endDate {
            times.append(currentDate)
            guard let newDate = calendar.date(byAdding: .minute, value: 15, to: currentDate) else { break }
            currentDate = newDate
        }
        
        return times
    }
}

Here's DayCellView:
import SwiftUI

struct DayCellView: View {
    var appointment: Appointment
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationLink(destination: AppointmentDetailView(appointment: appointment)
        ) {
            var dateString = appointment.date.formatted(date: .complete, time: .omitted)
            
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                
                
                HStack() {
                    Text("Resident Name:")
                    Text(appointment.firstName + " " + appointment.lastName)
                }
                .font(.headline)
                
                HStack {
                    Text("Appointment Date:")
                    Text(dateString)
                }
                
                HStack {
                    Text("Appointment Time:")
                    Text(appointment.time)
                }
                
                HStack {
                    Text("Description: ")
                    Text(appointment.description)
                }
                
                HStack {
                    Text("Is Appointment Confirmed? ")
                    
                    if appointment.hasRideScheduled {
                        Text("Confirmed")
                    } else {
                        Text("Not Confirmed Yet")
                    }
                }
            }
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
            .background(
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20)
                    .foregroundStyle(appointment.hasRideScheduled ? Color.green : Color.red)
                    .opacity(0.5)
                    
            )
        }
    }
}

Here's an excerpt of CalendarView where I call DayView:
LazyVGrid(columns: Array(repeating: GridItem(.flexible()), count: 7), spacing: 20) {
                    ForEach($selectedDates) { $value in
                        
                        ZStack(alignment: .bottom) {
                            if value.day != -1 {
                                NavigationLink{
                                    if let index = dateHasAppointment(date: value.date) {
                                        DayView( appointments: value.appointments, currentDate: value.date)
                                    } else {
                                        DayView(currentDate: value.date)
                                    }
                                } label: {
                                    Text("\(value.day)")
                                        .background() {
                                            ZStack(alignment: .bottom) {
                                              


How do you call DayView?
Note, you should not have @State var currentDate: Date in your DayView.
Depending on what you want, use for example: @Binding var currentDate: Date. Note also, to use NavigationLink you need to have a NavigationStack.

Your dates property is suspect.   You set some example values in the struct then immediately override them in .onAppear which itself uses a property that depends on how you call DayView.  Think about the context of your data and how you initialise DayView.

I added the section where I call DayView. I removed @State from currentDate, you are correct I didn't need it. This did not affect the List displaying.

How can you have
DayView( appointments: value.appointments, currentDate: value.date)
and DayView(appointments: value.appointments), something is not right here.

My apologies, I made a mistake in my edit. It's supposed to be DayView( appointments: value.appointments, currentDate: value.date) and DayView(currentDate: value.date).

Note, I suspect that your List of appointments does not display because it is inside a ScrollView. You could try giving it a frame.

Could you add .onAppear {print("---> appointment: \(appointment)")} to your DayCellView and show us what it prints.

List and ScrollView both greedily take space and malfunction if they are embedded within each other.

Instead of passing the whole appointment into the Cell the trick is to only pass in the properties it needs. That way the cell body is only called when the necessary things change instead of anything inside appointment that isnt even accessed.

I think the problem might be the scrollview, try putting it outside

Putting the list outside the scrollview created an empty space at the top of view. In most respects an improvement but still no text.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

try this approach, giving your List of appointments a frame height, such as:
        List {
            ForEach(appointments) { appointment in
                DayCellView(appointment: appointment)
            }
        }
        .frame(height: 456)  // <--- here

Here is my test code that displays the [Appointment] in the List.
// for testing
struct Appointment: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    var date: Date = Date()
    let name: String
    
    let firstName: String = "Mickey"
    let lastName: String = "Mouse"
    //.....
}

struct ContentView: View {
    // for testing
    let appointments: [Appointment] = [Appointment(name: "www"), Appointment(name: "xxx"),Appointment(name: "yyy"),Appointment(name: "zzz")]
    
    var body: some View {
       NavigationStack {
            DayView(appointments: appointments, currentDate: Date())
       }
    }
}

struct DayView: View {
    var appointments: [Appointment]  // <--- here
    var currentDate: Date // <--- here
    
    @State var dates = [
        Date(),
        Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .minute, value: 30, to: Date()),
        Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .hour, value: 60, to: Date()),
        Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .hour, value: 90, to: Date()),
        Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .hour, value: 120, to: Date())
    ].compactMap { $0 }
    
    @State var selectedDate: Date?

    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            
            List {
                ForEach(appointments) { appointment in
                    DayCellView(appointment: appointment)
                }
            }
            .frame(height: 456)  // <--- here, adjust as required

            VStack {
                Text(currentDate.description)
                Divider()
                    .padding(.vertical)
                Text("Select a Time")
                    .font(.largeTitle)
                    .bold()
                Text("Duration: 15 minutes")
                ForEach(dates, id: \.self) { date in
                    HStack {
                        Button {
                            withAnimation {
                                selectedDate = date
                            }
                        } label: {
                            Text(date.description)
                                .bold()
                                .padding()
                                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                                .foregroundColor(selectedDate == date ? .white : .blue)
                                .background(ZStack {
                                    if selectedDate == date {
                                        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10).foregroundColor(.gray)
                                    } else {
                                        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10).stroke()
                                    }
                                }
                                )
                        }
                    }
                }
                .padding(.horizontal)
            }
        }
        .navigationTitle(currentDate.description)
        .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
        .onAppear {
            dates = timesWith30MinuteIncrements(for: currentDate)
        }
    }
    
    func timesWith30MinuteIncrements(for date: Date) -> [Date] {
        let calendar = Calendar.current
        let startDate = calendar.date(bySettingHour: 8, minute: 0, second: 0, of: date)!
        let endDate = calendar.date(bySettingHour: 18, minute: 0, second: 0, of: date)!
        
        var times: [Date] = []
        var currentDate = startDate
        while currentDate <= endDate {
            times.append(currentDate)
            guard let newDate = calendar.date(byAdding: .minute, value: 15, to: currentDate) else { break }
            currentDate = newDate
        }
        return times
    }
}

struct DayCellView: View {
    var appointment: Appointment
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationLink(destination: Text("destination")
        ) {
            let dateString = appointment.date.formatted(date: .complete, time: .omitted)
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                HStack() {
                    Text("appointment Resident Name:")
                    Text(appointment.firstName + " " + appointment.lastName)
                }
                .font(.headline)
                HStack {
                    Text("Appointment Date:")
                    Text(dateString)
                }
                HStack {
                    Text("Appointment Time:")
                }
                HStack {
                    Text("Description: ")
                    Text(appointment.name)
                }
                HStack {
                    Text("Is Appointment Confirmed? ")
                }
            }
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
            .background(
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20)
                    .foregroundStyle(Color.green)
                    .opacity(0.5)
            )
        }
        .onAppear {
            print("---> appointment: \(appointment)") // <--- for testing
        }
    }
}


This, like MCipo's suggestion, created an empty space at the top of the view. No text was displayed.

Try using var appointments: [Appointment]  in your DayView.
If that does not work, then show a minimal reproducible code that produces your issue, see: Minimal code.  Currently there are too many missing parts to be able to reproduce your problem.

I removed all the code besides the list, and finally got it to display. Then I re-added the removed code. The list will only display if it's outside the scrollview area, and there's an annoyingly large white space between the appointment and the scrollview stuff, but it's still an improvement.

updated my answer with the test code I used to display the array of Appointments [Appointment] in the List. On MacOS 14.5, using Xcode 15.4, tested on real ios 17 devices and macCatalyst.

Apparently a list can't be placed inside of a scrollview. I ditched the list and just added a view inside the scrollview. The code now is:
import SwiftUI

struct DayView: View {
    var appointments: [Appointment] = []
    
    @State var residentAlertMessage = ""
    
    @State var residentAlert = false
    
    @State var dates = [
            Date(),
            Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .minute, value: 30, to: Date()),
            Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .hour, value: 60, to: Date()),
            Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .hour, value: 90, to: Date()),
            Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .hour, value: 120, to: Date())
        ]
        .compactMap { $0 }
    
    @State var selectedDate: Date?
    
    var currentDate: Date
    
    var body: some View {
        
        ScrollView {
            
            VStack {
                Text(currentDate.fullMonthDayYearFormat())
                
                Divider()
                VStack{
                    ForEach(appointments) { appointment in
                        DayCellView(appointment: appointment)
                    }
                }
                
                Divider()
                    .padding(.vertical)
                
                Text("Select a Time")
                    .font(.largeTitle)
                    .bold()
                
                Text("Duration: 15 minutes")
                
                ForEach(dates, id: \.self) { date in
                    HStack {
                        Button {
                            withAnimation {
                                selectedDate = date
                            }
                        } label: {
                           
                            Text( (date.timeFromDate()))
                                .bold()
                                .padding()
                                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                                .foregroundColor(selectedDate == date ? .white : .blue)
                                .background(ZStack {
                                    if selectedDate == date {
                                        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10).foregroundColor(.gray)
                                    } else {
                                        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10).stroke()
                                    }
                                }
                                )
                    }
                        if selectedDate == date {
                            NavigationLink {
                                if let resident = NetworkViewModel.resident {
                                    BookingView( appointment: Appointment(residentID: resident.id!, firstName: "", lastName: "", phoneNumber: "", date: selectedDate!, time: selectedDate!.timeFromDate(), description: "", house: "", residentAddress: "", addressOfAppt: "", hasRideScheduled: false))
                                }
                                
                            } label: {
                               Text("Next")
                                    .bold()
                                    .padding()
                                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                                    .background(
                                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
                                        .foregroundColor(.blue)
                                    )
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                .padding(.horizontal)
            }
        }
        .navigationTitle(currentDate.dayOfWeek())
        .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
        .onAppear {
            dates = timesWith30MinuteIncrements(for: currentDate)
        }
        
    }
    
    func timesWith30MinuteIncrements(for date: Date) -> [Date] {
        let calendar = Calendar.current
        let startDate = calendar.date(bySettingHour: 8, minute: 0, second: 0, of: date)!
        let endDate = calendar.date(bySettingHour: 18, minute: 0, second: 0, of: date)!
        
        var times: [Date] = []
        var currentDate = startDate
        while currentDate <= endDate {
            times.append(currentDate)
            guard let newDate = calendar.date(byAdding: .minute, value: 15, to: currentDate) else { break }
            currentDate = newDate
        }
        
        return times
    }
}

